# How can I input tags through a form (using acts_as_taggable_on) and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

Here is my form:

```
  1 <%= semantic_form_for @vendor do |f| %> 
  2     <% f.inputs do %> 
  3        <%= f.input :name %> 
  4        <%= f.input :tag_list %>    
  5     <% end %> 
  6     <%= f.buttons %> 
  7 <% end %>
```

Vendor.rb is acts_as_taggable_on.

However, when I enter strings into the field for tag_list, nothing gets stored when I go back into the console to check on vendor.tags.

What can I do to allow input of tags from a form?

```
 10   def new
 11     @vendor = Vendor.new
 12   end
 13   
 14   def create
 15     @vendor = Vendor.new(params[:vendor])
 16     if @vendor.save
 17       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created vendor."
 18       redirect_to @vendor
 19     else
 20       render :action => 'new'
 21     end
 22   end
```

Comment: @nash -- here is my controller....should I invoke separate @vendor.tag_list = something instead?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Show a model, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using attr_accessible in your model?

If yes, add :tag_list to it.

For Example:

attr_accessible :attr1, :tag_list